# juju: deploying lamp charm on ec2 causes instances to terminate

Tags: 13.04, juju, cloud, amazon-ec2

I was running a ubuntu 13.04 instance on ec2. I have juju .7 installed and bootstrapped. when I tried to deploy lamp, it caused the instance to terminate.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-62-73-113:~$ juju status
2013-05-15 22:11:58,102 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-05-15 22:11:58,877 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: ec2-54-224-187-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    instance-id: i-e26f328a
    instance-state: running
services: {}
2013-05-15 22:11:59,090 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
ubuntu@ip-10-62-73-113:~$ juju -v deploy lamp
2013-05-15 22:12:13,951 DEBUG Initializing juju deploy runtime
2013-05-15 22:12:13,952 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/lamp in charm store
2013-05-15 22:12:15,054 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-05-15 22:12:15,157 DEBUG Connecting to environment using ec2-54-224-187-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com...
2013-05-15 22:12:15,158 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="ec2-54-224-187-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com" remote_port="2181" local_port="45900".
2013-05-15 22:12:15,673:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@712: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.5
2013-05-15 22:12:15,673:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@716: Client environment:host.name=ip-10-62-73-113
2013-05-15 22:12:15,673:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@723: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-05-15 22:12:15,673:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@724: Client environment:os.arch=3.8.0-19-generic
2013-05-15 22:12:15,674:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@725: Client environment:os.version=#29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013
2013-05-15 22:12:15,674:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@733: Client environment:user.name=ubuntu
2013-05-15 22:12:15,675:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@741: Client environment:user.home=/home/ubuntu
2013-05-15 22:12:15,675:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@753: Client environment:user.dir=/home/ubuntu
2013-05-15 22:12:15,675:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@786: Initiating client connection, host=localhost:45900 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=0x7f1c731f3850 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x294a6f0 flags=0
2013-05-15 22:12:15,676:2914(0x7f1c6ee90700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1703: initiated connection to server [127.0.0.1:45900]
2013-05-15 22:12:16,215:2914(0x7f1c6ee90700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1750: session establishment complete on server [127.0.0.1:45900], sessionId=0x13eaa3f9e660004, negotiated timeout=30000
2013-05-15 22:12:16,218 DEBUG Environment is initialized.
2013-05-15 22:12:16,219 INFO Connected to environment.
2013-05-15 22:12:16,544 INFO Charm deployed as service: 'lamp'
2013-05-15 22:12:16,544:2914(0x7f1c746e6740):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_close@2505: Closing zookeeper sessionId=0x13eaa3f9e660004 to [127.0.0.1:45900]

2013-05-15 22:12:16,546 INFO 'deploy' command finished successfully
ubuntu@ip-10-62-73-113:~$ 
Broadcast message from root@ip-10-62-73-113
    (unknown) at 22:12 ...

The system is going down for power off NOW!
Connection to ec2-184-73-114-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to ec2-184-73-114-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
```

This happened twice in a row, so it doesn't seem like some freak accident.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. If anyone else has the problem:

I was putting the first instance, (the one I ran juju bootstrap on) in the same security group as all the instances juju creates.

When I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1161906
which describes how juju cleans up "orphaned" instances. Since my master instance was in the security group for the created instance, juju thought it was orphaned.

tl;dr: don't have your first instance in the same security group as the created instances.